# To show that $p_n(x) \to x$ for every $x \in X$ if and only if $(\|p_n\|)$ is a bounded sequence and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}R(p_n)$ is dense in $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach Space and Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence of projection operators in $BL(X)$ such that $R(p_n) \subset R(P_{n+1})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then Show that $p_n(x) \to x$ for every $x \in X$ if and only if $(\|p_n\|)$ is a bounded sequence and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}R(p_n)$ is dense in $X$

My try:

Suppose that $p_n(x) \to x$ for every $x \in X$. Then by Banach-Steinhaus Theorem $(\|p_n\|)$ is a bounded sequence. Then since $p_n(x) \to x$, the union is dense in $X$.

On the other hand suppose that $(\|p_n\|)$ is a bounded sequence and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty R(p_n)$ is dense in $X$. Let $x \in X$ be fixed.  Since the union is dense in $X$, there exists a $\{y_n\} \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty R(p_n)$ such that $y_n \to x$. Now $\|p_n\|$ is a bounded sequence. So there exists an $ \alpha \gt 0$ such that $\|p_n\| \lt \alpha$ for each $n$. Moreover each $p_n$ is a continuous linear map.Thus $p_k(y_n) \to p_k(x)$ for each $k$. Also $y_n=p_{j_n}(x_n)$(since $y_n \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty R(p_n)$). Thus $p_{j_{n}}(y_n)=p_{j_n}(x_n)=y_n$ which goes to $x$ as $n \to \infty$. Also $p_{j_{n}}(y_n) \to p_{j_{n}}(x)$.(since $P_{j_n}$ is continuous and $y_n \to x$)

Thus $$|p_n(x)-x| \le \|(p_n(x)-p_n(y_n))\|+\|(p_n(y_n)-p_{j_n}(y_n))\|+\|p_{j_n}(y_n)-x\|$$

The first and last terms can be made less than an arbitrary $\epsilon\gt 0$. For the middle one I make the following claim: >Since $ p_{j_n}(x_n)=y_n $, and $ p_{j_n} $ is a projection operator, $ p_{j_n}(y_n)=y_n $, I claim that $ p_{k}(y_n)=y_n $  for all $k \ge j_n $. Since the ranges are contained in one another, $ y_n=p_k (z_n) $ and $ p_k $ itself is a projection operator, $ p_k (y_n)=y_n $.  Thus for a large $ n $ , the middle one vanishes. Is that right? ?

Moreover The Banach property is needed for the first implication. The second implication will go through for an arbitrary normed space.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Starting from the first occurence of the word "Also." What is $x_n$? How is the sequence $j_n$ defined? How do you use the fact that $||p_n||<\alpha$? and for the first part, too:  where do you use the fact that $p_n$ are projections?

Comment: I am not using them in the first part. I don't need to. "also' part used the fact that $p_{j_n}$ are projections. Since each $y_n$ is in the union of the range of the projections, I can find such $x_n$. Now $||p_{j_n}(x-y_n)|| \lt \alpha |x-y_n|$. Here I am using $\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: @uniquesolution Now have a look.

Comment: @uniquesolution: I think the sentence in question could be more precisely phrased as "For each $n$ there exist $j_n, x_n$ such that $y_n = p_{j_n}(x_n)$."

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah right!!. What do you make of the try??

Comment: @Michael Hardy.. Can you suggest something about my try?? Can it be made better??